# SharePoint 2013 CMIS producer NTLM authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, authentication, ntlm, cmis

I was able to integrate with SharePoint 2013 CMIS producer only by using Basic HTTP Authentication! 

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945829.aspx#SP15CMIS_Authentication)  all other authentication methods are available, but so far I wasn't able to connect using NTLM or any other. 
BTW using SoapUI and running against SOAP service:

```
http://mydomain/sites/mysite/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/RepositoryService.svc
```

Testing SOAP Service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getRepositories/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At the same time SharePoint native web service for the same web application and site: 
`http://mydomain/sites/mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` 
runs with NTLM authentication just fine.

Comment: A customer reported the exact same problem, adding details here for info/searchability: Server is SharePoint 2010 with NTLM authentication, client is CMIS Workbench, configured with `Authentication: NTLM` and URL `https://server/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`, result in CMIS Workbench: `invalid argument: Bad request`. Could anyone please contact Microsoft so that they fix their product?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Unfortunately we don't have the option to contact Microsoft regarding their product. That is what every customer needs to do by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SharePoint Server supports these authentication methods:

- Anonymous AuthN
- Basic AuthN
- NTLM AuthN
- Digest AuthN
- Kerberos Protocol Transitioning/Constrained Delegation
- Windows-Claims
- Claims MultiAuth
- Claims Mixed Mode.

The CMIS Producer is available by default in SharePoint Server for on-premises deployment

Consider you create one app and it implements a `dictionary.Dictionary` that initializes all of the parameters. The parameters are used to authenticate to repositories, and specify data such as the binding that is in use the URL for the server to access the REST endpoint, user name, password, and the authentication provider class (for example, Basic AuthN).

After the parameters have been set up, the developer can use the `getRepositories` call to connect to each repository.